# Pop Up Chat Box

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions

Can someone let me know how to configure my Joomla site so that when someone visits my webpage a pop chat box appears where someone can ask questions.

You see these pop up chat boxes a lot on many sites that are selling services.

Comment: This does not come as a default feature. You will need to find an extension for this from the Joomla Extensions Directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla has no built-in chat option, but in addition to looking for a suitable extension at the [Joomla Extensions Directoy](http://extensions.joomla.org/), I suggest looking at some third-party live chat options. There are both free and commercial options available, depending on your requirements. They usually provide you with a simple code snippet that you can include in any website. If you add this code to your template's `index.php` file (`JOOMLAROOT\templates\YOURTEMPLATE\index.php`) it will be added to all your pages.

For further control, you can place the code inside a custom HTML module if you want to control on what pages the chat box is displayed. I recommend [Custom HTML Advanced](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-html-advanced) or similar, because the default Custom HTML module will probably strip out your code upon saving.

Some of the providers of live chat solutions are:

- [PureChat](http://purechat.com)
- [Zopim](http://zopim.com)
- [Olark](https://www.olark.com/)
- [LiveChat](http://livechat.com)
- [Tawk.to](https://www.tawk.to/)

There are many other options, try googling "live chat".

These chat solutions run on their own servers, thus taking load of your server, and most are mobile friendly. You can customize the look of your chat when you sign up for an account, and you get you own dashboard to interact with your clients.

Comment: Hi John this was the answer I was looking for

Comment: John, are there any you could recommend?

Comment: @cpatte7372 I'm glad it helped. And welcome to JSE. To accept an answer, please click the check mark on the left hand side of the answer you want to accept. I've used PureChat on several sites, but it all comes down to the features you're looking for.

Comment: Hi John, I see the check mark. I have one more question which I think is related to this question ... I'm going with Zopim for now. You mentioned where I should insert the snippet code, but each time I insert the code, I lose my site

Comment: The code is:<!--Start of Zopim Live Chat Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
_.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
$.src="//v2.zopim.com/?3I3JjfOxszMie8h425NCRI4SIES4vmiO";z.t=+new Date;$.
type="text/javascript";e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");
</script>
<!--End of Zopim Live Chat Script-->

Comment: Is there a specific place where I need to add the code?

Comment: Hello John, can I send you the PHP ?

Comment: *               
 */

// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
if(!defined('DS')){ define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); }

// Add JavaScript Frameworks
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');

// include framework classes and files
require_once('lib/gk.framework.php');
require_once('lib/framework/gk.const.php');

// run the framework
$tpl = new GKTemplate($this, $GK_TEMPLATE_MODULE_STYLES);

// EOF

Comment: You're using a Gavick template, so you should paste your code in the file `templates/YOURTEMPLATE/layouts/blocks/head.php`. At the end of the file should work fine.
BTW, I'm Johan... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [HeyBubble.com](http://heybubble.com) , installation is very easy and the chat system is reliable... you can also use it on your mobile with their app! We've been using it for a while now and it's great.