# Adding Code to Joomla for LiveChat

Tags: joomla-3.x, fix-my-code

I'm trying to add the following code to my templates `index.php`, but each time I add the code I break the site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
  d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
  _.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
  $.src="//v2.zopim.com/?3I3JjfOxszMie8h425NCRI4SIES4vmiO";z.t=+new Date;$.
  type="text/javascript";e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");
</script>
```

The name of the site that I'm getting the code from is Zopim - its a Live Chat site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your [previous question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/12427/pop-up-chat-box/12428#12428) I know you're using the [Gavick framework](https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla/gavern-framework/introduction). The `index.php` file is somewhat different from other templates, it loads all the parts of your website from other files.

The correct file to edit is `templates/YOURTEMPLATE/layouts/blocks/head.php`. Past your code at the end of this file and you should be good to go.

Another option is to use a Custom HTML module (e.g. [Custom HTML Advanced](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/custom-html-advanced)) to paste your code and publish the module to the pages where you want your live chat code to appear.

Comment: Hello John, thanks again for responding . Going to try your suggestions now. I'll let you know how I get on. Cheers

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it worked. (name's still Johan, though...:)